# Where is the source code for the Razor View Engine for ASP.NET MVC located?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to study the source of the Razor view engine. Since MS provides the source for MVC, I assumed that Razor's is available too... but have been unable to locate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Andrew, @JimSchubert's answer is actually correct nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source for MVC 3 Beta version of Razor is available here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/54306. However, this release is quite old and there have been a number of changes to Razor.

The final source for Razor will be made available soon after the release of MVC3 RTM

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, and I'm glad to hear that the release of the source is planned. Do you know if there is a reason why the source for the RC's has not been released?

Comment: We've been too busy with ongoing work and by the time we had some cycles to get around to it the next release was right around the corner and it didn't seem worth it. The way our sources are set up right now does not lend itself to easy source code releases. There are a number of manual steps involved. We'll look at making the whole process more automated for MVC 4 though.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but Microsoft just released the source code for Razor, WebMatrix.Data, System.Json, and a number of other ASP.NET stack technologies.

See the source code [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) . Apache 2.0 license.

Answer (score 1):

Well... even if source code is not available yet you can **practically** take a look using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (it's free). Just find the DLL(s) and import into Reflector.

However, please notice that reverse engineering **may** or **may not** be illegal in your country. In mine, it's perfectly legal, especially when your purpose is studying.

Comment: This is a good option too, I'd forgotten about reflector. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Source code for MVC is here

"Model view controller framework for building dynamic web sites with clean separation of concerns, including the merged MVC, Web API, and Web Pages w/ Razor."
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

"Parser and code generator for CSHTML files used in view pages for MVC web apps."
https://github.com/aspnet/Razor

And this has pointer for all .Net sources
https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet

Enjoy!